# Rotating a UIImage fixing angle turn

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIImage, and I want the user to be able to rotate it just like if it was the turning button of a safe. I don't want the image to turn at any angle in the range 0 < x < 360, but I want the wheel (the UIImage) to stop at one of the fixed points, which vary (normally form 0 to 20). If for example I have 3 options, the user will be able to turn the wheel and to place the pointer just on the three point (in this case at angles: 60, 120, 180).
I use this code to rotate the image:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    int len = [allTouches count]-1;

    UITouch *touch =[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:len];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[self.SplashItGroupPicker superview]];
    float theAngle = atan2( location.y-self.SplashItGroupPicker.center.y, location.x-self.SplashItGroupPicker.center.x );

    int totalRadians = -3.14;

    totalRadians += fabs(theAngle - totalRadians);
    totalRadians = fmod(totalRadians, 2*M_PI);

    [self rotateImage:totalRadians];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

-(void) rotateImage:(float)angleRadians{
    self.SplashItGroupPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians);
    CATransform3D rotatedTransform = self.SplashItGroupPicker.layer.transform;
    self.SplashItGroupPicker.layer.transform = rotatedTransform;
}
```

How can I obtain that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find how many radians you need per step, e.g. if you want 4 positions, then each position will be 3.14 / 4 radians more than the last.  Call this radIncrement.

After this line

```
totalRadians = fmod(totalRadians, 2*M_PI);
```

divide totalRadians by radIncrement, round the result to an integral value, then multiply it again by radIncrement.  You can change your rounding behavior to tweak when it changes positions.

Comment: but the totalRadius is not set correctly, i think, because the images is not rotating smoothly

Comment: What do you mean it is not rotating smoothly?  Do you want it to be animated?

Comment: When I move my finger its not following it